# Is using timers in deferred/promises implementation an evil?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, timer, promise, deferred

Many of my friends, who are using deeply some deferred/promises objects in their libraries, are often telling me, that to use timers in own implementation of it is an evil.

That it doesn't correspond to A+: https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec

And that many libraries as jQuery and others don't use timers. So I've tried to find any timers in jQuery sources, which may relate to promises implementation, but no success:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/deferred.js

All, right, but I've found some notes in A+ description, which have confused me about using timers in it:

At `Notes` article:

> Here "platform code" means engine, environment, and promise
>   implementation code. In practice, this requirement ensures that
>   onFulfilled and onRejected execute asynchronously, after the event
>   loop turn in which then is called, and with a fresh stack. This can be
>   implemented with either a "macro-task" mechanism such as **setTimeout or
>   setImmediate**, or with a "micro-task" mechanism such as
>   MutationObserver or process.nextTick. Since the promise implementation
>   is considered platform code, it may itself contain a task-scheduling
>   queue or "trampoline" in which the handlers are called.

So, I understood A+ didn't have strict rules about timer using or did it?

Help me, I'm rather confused.

Comment: *Where* would they use timers in their promise implementation that they consider it evil?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing the use of `setTimeout` with "setting a timer" - Promises/A+ implementations typically use `setTimeout` *to guarantee asynchronous execution* of handler functions, not to delay execution by some time period.

Promises/A+ guarantees that the fulfilled and rejected methods are called asynchronously, regardless of when the promise is fulfilled. One way to guarantee async execution in a browser JS environment is to wrap a function call in `setTimeout` with a timeout of zero (the default).

jQuery does not guarantee asyc execution of fulfilled/rejected callbacks (which is [a major design flaw](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/Coming-from-jQuery)), so an async wrapper call is not required.

Answer (score 1):

Using timers in general in your applications is a bad practice (other than scheduling tasks, that is).

You can never be sure how long an action will take. So you end up doing one of three things:

- You either allocate not enough time, in which case, stuff breaks because some things you expected to happen hadn't happened yet.
- Or you allocate too much time, in which case you application is slow for no good reason
- Or, worst case, you allocate **just enough** time, which causes your application to *sometimes* break, and sometimes work as expected.

I'm not sure about specs and stuff. But using timers and delays in your application in general is a bad idea.